# How can I get elements within a certail interval from an array in perl?

Tags: perl

I have a list of intervals (around 42000) and an array of values (few million) and I want to get value from the longer list of values for each interval.

Is there a way (or module) I can directly extract values within each interval instead of looping through all values and comparing with interval within the loop for each interval. This is very time-consuming.

For example:

```
foreach my $read_pos ( keys %{ $reads{$chr} } ) {  #$reads{$chr} is the list of all values
    if ( ( $read_pos >= $utr_start ) && ( $read_pos <= $utr_end ) ) { #$utr_start and $utr_end are intervals
        push( @{ $reads_tsx{$acc} }, $read_pos );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `slice`:

```
@reads_tsx = @reads[$utr_start, $utr_end];
```

Example:

```
@nums = (1..200);
@slicenums = @nums[10..20];
print "@slicenums";
```

Result:

```
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

If you want several intervals, it is possible also:

```
@nums = (1..200);
@slicenums = @nums[10..15,50..55,140..145];
print "@slicenums";
```

Result:

```
11 12 13 14 15 16 51 52 53 54 55 56 141 142 143 144 145 146
```

And if you have a hash, not a list:

```
%vals = (
    10 => "s10",
    30 => "s30",
    50 => "s50",
);
@nums = (0..200);
@slicenums = grep { exists($vals{$_}) } @nums[10..15,50..55,140..145];
print "@slicenums\n";
print "@vals{@slicenums}\n";
```

Result:

```
$ perl 1.pl
10 50
s10 s50
```

Here `s10` and `s50` are correspondent values for keys that get to the intervals: `10..15,50..55,140..145`